# Phonegap Build Error with multidex dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-multidex

I'm trying to export my apk but I'm receiving one build error below:

[image]

I've added    `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` in my build.gradle dependencies, enabled multidex in my defaultConfig and also added `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">` within my Android Manifest file but am still receiving the error.

===============================

My build.gradle can be found here: 
http://pastie.org/10902207

================================

What is going on? Can anyone give me some insight as to why I am receiving this?

Comment: Add your build.gradle file please.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine the issue you are having is because you do not have a minSDK defined in your Build.gradle. The library you are trying to uses minSDKVersion 4.

If you don't specify your minSDKVersion your project is going to automatically default to version 1. Try adding something like the below to your build.gradle file.

```
android{
    compiledSdkVersion 23 //marshmallow
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
          minSdkVersion 11 //honeycomb
          targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate the answer basic. So I just added minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in the defaultconfig. It ran the build fine with no errors when I added 22 as the minSdk however I'm trying to do 19.

It's saying minSdkVersion19 cannot be smaller than version 22 -- version 22 is declared in my plugin's androidmanifest.xml file. I tried changing that number to 19 in the androidmanifest but it keeps reverting back to 22 and I get the build error. Any ideas?

Comment: if I try adding compiledSdkVersion in the build.gradle, I get a gradle DSL method not found: 'compiledSdkVersion()' error

Comment: @chronotrigga can you add both your build.gradle as well as the androidmanifest to your main question please?

Comment: I've added it for you. The androidmanifest.xml is my project's actual androidmanifest.xml. The new error is still reference the plugin file but it seems like no matter what hard edit I do it just reverts back: http://i.imgur.com/sLNKar9.png

Comment: @chronotrigga you have two different SDK versions defined. 19 in your gradle and 10 in your manifest.   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="23" /> 

I looked at the source for that plugin and it uses a min version of 9 so it seems you have deeper issues (at least if you are using version 3.18.1

Comment: That's strange. I followed the plugin path and the plugin's androidmanifest says 22. Is there a way I can override that?

Comment: Sure in your manifest add: <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook.android" />

Comment: I changed the 10 in my manifest to 19 so everything matches and also included the uses-sdk but am still getting the error. I know you mentioned I may have deeper issues but it seems like it's only telling me about the minSdk being smaller than x, so I can't see the real error. Do you have any other recommendations? Really appreciate the help!

Comment: @chronotrigga one last thing. Try adding this to the facebook lib manifest: 

    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.facebook.android">
    <application/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
</manifest>


Then update the file com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookLib/project.properties

with this:

android.library=true
target=android-22

Comment: still the same, strange! also the project.properties was already android.library=true target=android-22

Comment: @chronotrigga unfortunately I am at the end here. Without actually debugging your project I am at a loss. Sorry mate.